foreach statement does not contain public instance
I'm making a build system but 2 lines are giving the following error and I can't seam to fix it.
Line:5+11
private void ghostifyModel(Transform modelParent, Material ghostMaterial = null)
{
    if (ghostMaterial != null)
    {
        foreach(MeshRenderer meshRenderer in modelParent.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            meshRenderer.material = ghostMaterial;
        }
    }else
    {
        foreach (Collider modelColliders in modelParent.GetComponentInChildren<Collider>()) 
        {
            modelColliders.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Build Objects")]
    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> floorObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> wallObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    [Header("Build Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private SelectedBuildType currentBuildType;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask connecterLayer;
    
    [Header("Ghost Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private Material ghostMaterialValid;
    [SerializeField] private Material ghostMaterialInvalid;
    [SerializeField] private float connectorOverlapRadius = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float maxGroundAngle = 45f;
    
    [Header("Internal State")]
    [SerializeField] private bool isBuilding = false;
    [SerializeField] private int currentBuildingIndex;
    private GameObject ghostBuildGameobject;
    private bool isGostInvalidPosition = false;
    private Transform ModelParent = null;
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
            isBuilding = !isBuilding;
    
        if (isBuilding)
        {
            ghostBuild();
    
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                placeBuild();
        }
        else if (ghostBuildGameobject)
        {
            Destroy(ghostBuildGameobject);
            ghostBuildGameobject = null;
        }
    }
    
    private void ghostBuild()
    {
        GameObject currentBuild = getCurrentBuild();
        createGhostPrefab(currentBuild);
    
        moveGhostPrefabToRaycast();
        checkBuildValidity();
    }
    
    private void createGhostPrefab(GameObject currentBuild)
    {
        if (ghostBuildGameobject == null)
        {
            ghostBuildGameobject = Instantiate(currentBuild);
    
            ModelParent = ghostBuildGameobject.transform.GetChild(0);
    
            ghostifyModel(ModelParent, ghostMaterialValid);
            ghostifyModel(ghostBuildGameobject.transform);
        }
    }
    
    private void moveGhostPrefabToRaycast()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            ghostBuildGameobject.transform.position = hit.point;
        }
    }
    
    private void checkBuildValidity()
    {
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(ghostBuildGameobject.transform.position, connectorOverlapRadius);
        if (colliders.Length > 0)
        {
            ghostConnectBuild(colliders);
        }
        else
        {
            ghostSeperateBuild();
        }
    }
    
    private void ghostConnectBuild(Collider[] colliders)
    {
        Connector bestConnector = null;
    
        foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
        {
            Connector connector = collider.GetComponent<Connector>();
    
            if (connector.canConnectTo)
            {
                bestConnector = connector;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if (bestConnector == null || currentBuildType == SelectedBuildType.floor && bestConnector.isConnectedToFloor || currentBuildType == SelectedBuildType.wall && bestConnector.isConnectedToWall)
        {
            ghostifyModel(ModelParent, ghostMaterialInvalid);
            isGostInvalidPosition = false;
            return;
        }
    
        snapGhostPrefabToConnector(bestConnector);
    }
    
    private void snapGhostPrefabToConnector(Connector connector)
    {
        Transform ghostConnector = findSnapConnecter(connector.transform, ghostBuildGameobject.transform.GetChild(1));
        ghostBuildGameobject.transform.position = connector.transform.position - (ghostConnector.position - ghostBuildGameobject.transform.position);
    
        if (currentBuildType == SelectedBuildType.wall)
        {
            Quaternion newRotation = ghostBuildGameobject.transform.rotation;
            newRotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(newRotation.eulerAngles.x, connector.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, newRotation.eulerAngles.z);
            ghostBuildGameobject.transform.rotation = newRotation;
        }
    
        ghostifyModel(ModelParent, ghostMaterialValid);
        isGostInvalidPosition = true;
    }
    
    private void ghostSeperateBuild()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (currentBuildType == SelectedBuildType.wall)
            {
                ghostifyModel(ModelParent, ghostMaterialInvalid);
                isGostInvalidPosition = false;
            }
    
            if (hit.collider.transform.root.CompareTag("Buildables"))
            {
                ghostifyModel(ModelParent, ghostMaterialInvalid);
                isGostInvalidPosition = false;
            }
    
            if (Vector3.Angle(hit.normal, Vector3.up) < maxGroundAngle)
            {
                ghostifyModel(ModelParent, ghostMaterialValid);
                isGostInvalidPosition = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ghostifyModel(ModelParent, ghostMaterialInvalid);
                isGostInvalidPosition = false;
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    private Transform findSnapConnecter(Transform snapConnector, Transform ghostConnectorParent)
    {
        ConnectorPosition OppositeConnectorTag = getOppositePosition(snapConnector.GetComponent<Connector>());
        foreach (Connector connector in ghostConnectorParent.GetComponentsInChildren<Connector>())
        {
            if (connector.connectorPosition == OppositeConnectorTag)
                return connector.transform;
        }
    
        return null;
    }
    
    private ConnectorPosition getOppositePosition(Connector connector)
    {
        ConnectorPosition position = connector.connectorPosition;
    
        if (currentBuildType == SelectedBuildType.wall && connector.connectorParentType == SelectedBuildType.wall)
            return ConnectorPosition.bottom;
    
        if (currentBuildType == SelectedBuildType.floor && connector.connectorParentType == SelectedBuildType.wall && connector.connectorPosition == ConnectorPosition.top)
            if (connector.transform.root.rotation.y == 0)
            {
                return GetConnectorClosestToPlayer(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return GetConnectorClosestToPlayer(false);
            }
    
        switch (position)
        {
            case ConnectorPosition.left:
                return ConnectorPosition.right;
            case ConnectorPosition.right:
                return ConnectorPosition.left;
            case ConnectorPosition.top:
                return ConnectorPosition.bottom;
            case ConnectorPosition.bottom:
                return ConnectorPosition.top;
            default:
                return ConnectorPosition.bottom;
        }
    
    }
    
    private ConnectorPosition GetConnectorClosestToPlayer(bool topBottom)
    {
        Transform cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    
        if (topBottom)
        {
            return cameraTransform.position.z >= ghostBuildGameobject.transform.position.z ? ConnectorPosition.bottom : ConnectorPosition.top;
        }
        else
            return cameraTransform.position.x >= ghostBuildGameobject.transform.position.x ? ConnectorPosition.left : ConnectorPosition.right;
    
    }
    
    private void ghostifyModel(Transform modelParent, Material ghostMaterial = null)
    {
        if (ghostMaterial != null)
        {
            foreach(MeshRenderer meshRenderer in modelParent.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
            {
                meshRenderer.material = ghostMaterial;
            }
        }else
        {
            foreach (Collider modelColliders in modelParent.GetComponentInChildren<Collider>()) 
            {
                modelColliders.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public enum SelectedBuildType
{
    floor,
    wall,
}

I tried fixing it myself but I am only starting with scripts so I couldn't figure it out.

First, it is important to read the error message carefully. It probably says something like:

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'MeshRenderer' because 'MeshRenderer' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Most collections expose a GetEnumerator method. This method allows the collection to be enumerated.
GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>() returns a single item of type MeshRenderer which is not a collection, where as GetComponentsInChildren (note the plural "s" in "Components") returns an enumeration. Use the latter method.
Note that most IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) have mechanisms allowing you to explore the objects and structures you are using in your code. It is called IntelliSense in Visual Studio and in Visual Studio Code. Use this information! It helps you to understand which parameters a method requires and what it returns (among many other things).

Thanks for your help I appreciate it I used the latter and it fixed my problem

@durandcoetzee: so if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please accept this answer. This will show your appreciation for the people who spent their own time to help you.
